# How can I click an Android Action Bar item under program control?

Tags: android

PeterH posted the following code:

```
//initiate the button
button.performClick();
button.setPressed(true); 
button.invalidate(); 
// delay completion till animation completes
button.postDelayed(new Runnable() {  //delay button 
public void run() {  
    button.setPressed(false); 
    button.invalidate();
    //any other associated action
 }
}, 800);  // .8secs delay time
```

Can the same type of operation be performed for Action Bar items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can save MenuItem as a field and then call onOptionsItemSelected(savedMenuItem). But as ActionBar items are MenuItems and not Buttons (of course, if your action bar isn't customized with view like http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidActionBar/article.html#actionbar_dynamic). But if your ActionBar is customized with view and that view has a Button, that Button's behaviour can be customized as considered in your code snippet.
Example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

MenuItem item;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setSubtitle("mytest");
    actionBar.setTitle("TESTESTEST");

    TextView tView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_settings) {
        this.item = item;
        Toast.makeText(this, "settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Unfortunately, my Action Bar is the generic flavor. I'll save the code just in case I decide to change my UI. Thanks.